# Combine multiple columns and rows into one column

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to combine multiple columns and rows into one column. The order does from left to right in row 1 then goes to row 2 and follow the sequence again. Here is an example:

Current df:

```
Shop  A  B  C  D  E
1     A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
2     A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
3     A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
4     A4 B4 C4 D4 E4
5     A5 B5 C5 D5 E5
```

Desired output:

```
Combined
A1
B1
C1
D1
E1
A2
B2
C2
.
.
.
D5
E5
```

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: @uguros Yes, I am using Pandas

Answer (score 2):

If `Shop` is index name, no column use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('Combined')
print (df)
   Combined
0        A1
1        B1
2        C1
3        D1
4        E1
5        A2
6        B2
7        C2
8        D2
9        E2
10       A3
11       B3
12       C3
13       D3
14       E3
15       A4
16       B4
17       C4
18       D4
19       E4
20       A5
21       B5
22       C5
23       D5
24       E5
```

else if there is column `Shop` use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in first step:

```
df = df.set_index('Shop').stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('Combined')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `transpose` and then `melt`:

```
df = df.set_index("Shop")  # should not be needed
df.transpose().melt()
```

Output:

```
    Shop value
0      1    A1
1      1    B1
2      1    C1
3      1    D1
4      1    E1
5      2    A2
6      2    B2
7      2    C2
8      2    D2
9      2    E2
10     3    A3
...
```

And you can now of course drop 'shop', it you'd like to:

```
df.transpose().melt().drop("Shop", axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   value
0     A1
1     B1
2     C1
3     D1
4     E1
5     A2
6     B2
7     C2
8     D2
9     E2
10    A3
...
```

Comment: Like `df.transpose().melt(value_name='Combined').drop("Shop", axis=1)`, removed downvote.